# Passing API through HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I'm learning API calls and I'm not exactly sure how to authenticate my HttpURLConnection. I understand that I need to add the key I received through the third party to my header, but I'm not sure how to do that exactly. When I substitute a different url, I receive an output of 200. With the url included in my code, I get a 401 response. Here's my code below:

```
package FortniteTrackerAPI;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

    private static HttpURLConnection connection;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
      try {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/{platform}/{chapel thrill}");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Request setup
          connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
          connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
          connection.setReadTimeout(5000);

          int status = connection.getResponseCode();
          System.out.println(status);

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using JDK >= 11, I would consider using the new [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) API instead.

Comment: If this is about HTTP Basic Authentication, all you have to do is send back a header with the user and password. See [this](https://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add addRequestProperty to the connection and call connection timeout method before calling GET method.
Here is the edited code:-

`
public class Main {

```
private static HttpURLConnection connection;
public static void main(String[] args) {

try {
    URL url = new URL("https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/{platform}/{chapel thrill}");
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:221.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0");

 
    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    int status = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(status);

} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

}

`